What makes $\frac{1}{z}$ special in complex residues?
I'm going back over some introductory complex analysis, and I'm trying to find an intuitive notion of what makes the $\frac{1}{z}$ term special when calculating complex closed line integrals of analytic functions. My current understanding follows the chain of reasoning:

Take $f$ as analytic, so $f$ can be locally understood around $z=0$ as a power series $a_iz^i$. Suppose also that $f$ has an isolated zero at $z=0$, so that $i$ ranges from $n$ to $\infty$, for some negative integer $n$.
The line integral $\int_C f\,\text{ds}$ can thus be locally understood as $\int_C a_iz^i\,\text{ds}$ (assume $C$ is closed, well-behaved, and avoids $0$).
For each $z^i$, $i\neq -1$, we have $\int z^i\,\text{dz}=\frac{1}{i+1}z^{i+1}+c$, and these antiderivatives are analytic away from $0$, so that $\int_C z^i\,\text{ds}=0$.
The function $z^{-1}$ is different in that its antiderivative $\text{Log}(z)$ is multi-valued on $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$, and so the line integral must be evaluated in a way that is always locally on the same branch. A closed line integral with winding number $n$ will have shifted by $n$ branches by the time it ends, and so will have accumulated an integral of $2\pi in$; one step of $2\pi i$ per rotation around the zero.
We obtain residues by simply applying linearity of the integral, so we get a residue of $2\pi ina_{-1}$ around the pole at zero.

This all makes sense to me - I've studied topology, so the idea of "lifting" the line $C$ to its image in the multi-sheeted codomain of $\text{Log}$ is fine. However, despite following the technical reasoning, I'm still left without an intuitive grasp of why the term of $z^{-1}$ in the power series expansion of $f$ is "special" in this way. Do I just need to accept this as a fact of life, as being due to the non-holomorphicity of its antiderivative, or is there something deeper that makes it all seem more natural?

I think the high-brow answer is that the function $1/z$ is a fundamental solution of the Cauchy-Riemann operator.  See the Wikipedia article here. That $1/z$ is a fundamental solution is, at the end of the day, a result of Green's Theorem (i.e., Stokes Theorem in the plane).

Topologically, the relevant thing about $1/z$ is that $\frac{1}{z}dz = i,d\theta$, using $z = re^{i\theta}$.

In my opinion the "original sin" committed by $z^{-1}$ is the one you noted already, and is a mystery that already arises in one-variable calculus: there's a "hole" in the table of derivatives and antiderivatives of $x^n$ as $n$ ranges over the integers, because the derivative of $x^0$ is $0$ instead of something interesting times $x$ to the negative one. (In a sense, this is the original sin of "no division by zero.")
Of course there is an antiderivative -- the logarithm -- this is often how one defines the logarithm in a from-the-foundations approach to calculus -- but you have to exit the family of power functions to get there, and this makes $x^{-1}$ unique among power functions. In the complex plane, there is no antiderivative of $1/z$ holomorphic (or even continuous) on the unit circle and so you wind up with an error term from switching the branches. Again, all this, you already are happy with based on your presentation.
However, there's another framing which you don't mention, which you might find more satisfying if you don't like the above. Take the definition of a complex integral as a real line integral. Then, by parametrizing the circle, you can compute directly that the integral of $z^n$ around the unit circle vanishes unless $n = -1$, in which case it is $2 \pi i$.

This last framing seems to bypass the involvement of $\text{Log}$ and its multi-valued-ness; is there an intuition attached to this framing for the exceptionality of $n=-1$? Or is it another case of "see equations"?

I don't know if you'll like this or think it's just another artifact of calculation. When you do the integral of $z^n$ around the circle, if you parametrize with $z = \exp(2 \pi i t)$, then you get $dz = 2 \pi i \exp(2 \pi i t)dt$ and so, critically, $dt$ is like $dz/z$, in other words, the function you're integrating from $0$ to $1$ winds up being $exp(2 \pi i(n+1)t)$ with that shift by $1$. Now the relevant "original sin" is that $\int_0^{2\pi} \cos(mx)$ vanishes by periodicity unless $m = 0$.

Oh! I really like this, a no-symbols reframing of the above comment: geometrically, if you start at $(1, 0)$ and go around the circle $m$ times (negative $m$ means go the wrong way), the average value of the $y$-coordinate is $0$ for any $m$ and for the $x$-coordinate it is $0$ unless $m=0$ in which case you're just stuck at $1$ for the $2 \pi i$ amount of time you're on the circle, so the average value is $1/(2 \pi)$. The line integral formula tells you that the complex integral is just this average value but with a shift by one.

(too late to edit my comment but the average value is 1 of course, not 1/2pi)

I've been looking at it and coming away with similar perspectives - a fun one is that if you let $n$ vary freely in $\mathbb{R}$, you obtain a function mapping $n$ to $\int_{S^1}z^{n}\text{ds}$ whose real and imaginary components are scalings of $\frac{sin(2\pi(n+1))}{n+1}$ and $\frac{cos(2\pi(n+1))}{n+1}$, respectively. The exceptionalism of $n=-1$ is then less so - the numerator goes to $0$ as with all other natural numbers, but the function becomes nonzero in the limit, which is the exceptional part.
